# Wazuh active response with VirusTotal is not working

Tags: wazuh

Wanted to integrate with VirusTotal and Yara but it seems like active response doesn't work as expected by following the steps in the link below:
https://documentation.wazuh.com/current/user-manual/capabilities/active-response/ar-use-cases/removing-malware.html

After adding/downloading eicar.com in /root directory, and read ossec.log, I get the following output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**About VirusTotal**
I just followed the [documentation](https://documentation.wazuh.com/current/user-manual/capabilities/active-response/ar-use-cases/removing-malware.html) and it worked well for me in Wazuh Manager 4.3.4 and a Wazuh Agent of the same version.
I got those same messages in `/var/ossec/logs/ossec.log` of the Wazuh Agent, those appear when the files do not exist or the proper permissions are not assigned, those [files](https://documentation.wazuh.com/4.1/user-manual/capabilities/active-response/how-it-works.html#default-active-response-scripts) were replaced already in [4.2](https://documentation.wazuh.com/4.2/user-manual/capabilities/active-response/how-it-works.html#default-active-response-scripts) but still show up in the log, since you are trying to use the script from the documentation then do not worry about those messages.

- If you check under `/var/ossec/logs/active-responses.log` do you get any error?
- What version of Wazuh Manager and Wazuh Agent are you using?

**About Yara**
It shouldn't be related to VirusTotal and probably deserves a different post, there is an [issue](https://github.com/wazuh/wazuh/issues/14055) open here but seems it is working, probably [this comment](https://github.com/wazuh/wazuh/issues/14055#issuecomment-1171230729) helps you troubleshooting that one

Comment: I am using Wazuh manager 4.2.7. I only got restart-agent.sh log in /var/ossec/logs/active-responses.log and nothing else

Comment: Everything is working fine now. I placed the wrong configuration in the wrong endpoint.

Comment: Glad to know it is working now!

Answer (score 0):

The Active Response module is managed from the Wazuh Manager in `/var/ossec/etc/ossec.conf`, from here you can enable the response you need to execute using an `<active response>` configuration block that will use a "**command**" as a response. For example, if you are going to enable "**remove-threat**" as an Active Response on any agent that triggers the VirusTotal rule, you should have a `<command>` block and also an `<active-response>` block for that particular case, the same goes for any other AR case you may want to use.

```
<command>
   <name>remove-threat</name>
   <executable>remove-threat.sh</executable>
   <timeout_allowed>no</timeout_allowed>
</command>




<active-response>
    <disabled>no</disabled>
    <command>remove-threat</command>
    <location>local</location>
    <rules_id>87105</rules_id>
</active-response>
```

The Response (script) needs to be present on each agent under `/var/ossec/active-response/bin/`. If you are only using the "**remove-threat**" Active Response, you should only have a single `<active-response>` block on the Manager's configuration file. Each `<active-response>` block within the Manager's "**ossec.conf**" must have a matching `<command>` block that is basically the response (script) the module is going to use. Perhaps you can share with us this configuration file so we can take a look.

Also, the following output from the Manager will be useful to see if the integration with Virustotal is being activated:

```
cat /var/ossec/logs/ossec.log | grep wazuh-integratord
```

I hope this helps,

Let us know